# xcode gcc compiler showing argument list too long

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

i m trying to complie a .cpp file in Xcode 3.2.6 in Snow Leapord 10.6.8.

I m getting

```
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: error trying to exec '/Developer/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/cc1plus': execv: Argument list too long
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

while compiling using gcc 4.2 and even tried compiling with gcc 4.0

Can someone provide any pointers on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not working with Mac, but had the same error on Ubuntu. I pass too much of arguments to gcc input. Try to check your gcc parameters.